# Netlogo count patches with neighbors of specific color

Tags: netlogo

How can I code to know how many patches are in my world that have yellow neighbors? I'm using the following line:

```
ask patches [ show count neighbors with [pcolor = yellow] ]
```

The result is a long list of each patch answering the question, but all that I need is the number of patches that fulfill the mentioned condition. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want

```
print count patches with [ any? neighbors with [ pcolor = yellow ] ]
```